# GRPC: keep a reference to stream to send data to multiple clients

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I am starting with GRPC using go. I read the official docs, and few examples.

In most examples, you don't identify the client, but use the stream to read / write data.
I see there is API in Context to retrieve auth info, and can indentify the client for the ChatRequest.
But, what if I want to keep a reference / index to the Stream based on the client id.

For example,

say I have 3 users in a chat room. I represent the rpc as (it could be server-streaming as well)

```
rpc Chat(stream ChatRequest) returns (stream ChatResponse) {}
```

say, one user send a message to  the group, which need to send to other 2. So, if I need to send it through the 
Stream currently opened for those users, how safe is to keep a reference of the stream.

The implementation will be like...

```
type chatServiceServer struct {
    // keep a map of subscribers / users currently connected; protect with mutex
}

func (s *chatServiceServer) Chat(stream pb.ChatService_ChatServer) error {
    // md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(stream.Context())
    // p, ok := peer.FromContext(ctx)
    // ... identify client from above

    for {
        // save the message to DB
        // find other users in the chatroom is currently connected
        // if so, stream.Send(m)
        // else notify ....
    }
}
```

But, I see the warnings in API doc and wonder a better way.

```
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#ServerStream
// It is safe to have a goroutine calling SendMsg and another goroutine
// calling RecvMsg on the same stream at the same time, but it is not safe
// to call SendMsg on the same stream in different goroutines.
SendMsg(m interface{}) error
```

Similar use case arise with any subscription (event, ....), and need to notify based on client id. Any example code, article would be great as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be safe to save the stream for use elsewhere, but you may only call `SendMsg` in a single goroutine (the same limitation is true for `RecvMsg`, independently).  So this means if you do this in your method handler:

```golang
for {
  if err := stream.Recv(req); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  for _, s := range allStreams[req.ID] {
    if err := s.Send(req.Message); err != nil { /* remove s from allStreams */ }
  }
}
```

Then the call to `s.Send` *must* be guarded by a lock, because multiple of these handlers may be running concurrently.  (Also `allStreams` is assumed to be a `map[ID][]stream`, in which case it must also be guarded by a lock.)